# Skype and steam will not run at the same time

Tags: skype, steam

Every time I launch steam, it crashes Skype. It claims `Unable to sign in due to a disk I/O error, try restarting skype to fix this.` I have restarted skype, and that gave me no results.

This problem happened when I was using ubuntu 13, and went away for a while when I updated to 14.04. It's back and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: So after fidling around for a while, I got skype to work while I was running steam. it runs for about 1/2 hour and then it closes and I can't open it again.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this seems to be a common error. There is only a guide for Windows which can be found here: [CLICK](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10143/why-do-i-get-a-disk-i-o-error-when-i-try-to-sign-in-to-skype-for-windows-desktop)

But you might be able to do the same in Ubuntu. In the guide they delete some kind of profile folder. You could try the same. But be sure to do a backup first.

Comment: Honestly, I'd like someone to figure out how to do this on ubuntu and post a guide here

Answer (score 0):

We can do the fix as follows.

```
cd ~/.Skype/
mv loginaccnt loginaccnt_bak
ps -aux | grep skype
pkill -f skype
```

Then restart Skype and login. It will work.